# How two RDD according to funcation get Result RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I am a beginner of Apache Spark. I want to filter two RDD into result RDD with the below code

```
def runSpark(stList:List[SubStTime],icList:List[IcTemp]): Unit ={
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("OD").setMaster("local[*]")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val st = sc.parallelize(stList).map(st => ((st.productId,st.routeNo),st)).groupByKey()
val ic = sc.parallelize(icList).map(ic => ((ic.productId,ic.routeNo),ic)).groupByKey()
//TODO
//val result = st.join(ic).mapValues( )
sc.stop()
}
```

here is what i want to do

```
List[ST] ->map ->Map(Key,st) ->groupByKey ->Map(Key,List[st])
List[IC] ->map ->Map(Key,ic) ->groupByKey ->Map(Key,List[ic])
STRDD join ICRDD get Map(Key,(List[st],List[ic]))
```

I have a function compare listST and listIC get the List[result] result contains both SubStTime and IcTemp information

```
  def calcIcSt(st:List[SubStTime],ic:List[IcTemp]): List[result]
```

I don't know how to use mapvalues or other some way to get my result

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
val result = st.join(ic).mapValues( x => calcIcSt(x._1,x._2) )
```